# javascript object in rocket syntax

Tags: javascript, hashrocket

I want to get a value from this hash in JavaScript:

```
hash=    {:user_authenticated=>false, :user_email=>"nope"}

hash.user_authenticated

hash[user_authenticated]

hash["user_authenticated"]

hash[:user_authenticated]
```

Nothing seems to work. I get this error:

`SyntaxError: invalid property id`

Comment: That looks like Ruby, not JavaScript?

Comment: Javascript object is like {'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2', ...}

Answer (score 8):

Javascript objects **may not be expressed with the rocket syntax** like Ruby's hashes.

However, as ECMAScript 6 is adopted, Javascript implementations have gained the ability to use the same symbol, `=>` for **anonymous function definitions**, though they are referred to as *arrow functions* or colloquially as *fat arrows* rather than *hash rockets*.

For simple functions, there is no difference between definitions with the arrow syntax and traditional functions.

```
var foo = function (s) { return s.toString() }
```

and

```
function foo(s) { return s.toString() }
```

are equivalent to:

```
var foo = (s) => { return s.toString() }
```

additionally, these are both equivalent to:

```
var foo = (s) => s.toString()
```

as well as:

```
const foo = s => s.toString()
```

However, when using `this`, the choice between traditional and arrow functions matters, as traditionally defined functions create a new scope for `this`, whereas arrow functions do not. Examples from [the Mozilla doc on Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) by [Mozilla Contributors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions$history)  (licensed under [CC-BY-SA 2.5](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/)):

```
function Person() {
  // The Person() constructor defines `this` as an instance of itself.
  this.age = 0;

  setInterval(function growUp() {
    // In non-strict mode, the growUp() function defines `this` 
    // as the global object, which is different from the `this`
    // defined by the Person() constructor.
    this.age++;
  }, 1000);
}

var p = new Person();
```

Here, `p.age` will always be 0 because the `age` that is incremented belongs to a `this` which only exists within the inner function, not the instance of `Person` which is `p`. When the inner function is defined as an arrow function:

```
function Person() {
  // The Person() constructor defines `this` as an instance of itself.
  this.age = 0;

  setInterval(() => {
    // In non-strict mode, the growUp() function defines `this` 
    // as the global object, which is different from the `this`
    // defined by the Person() constructor.
    this.age++;
  }, 1000);
}

var p = new Person();
```

`p.age` will be equal to the number of seconds since `p` was created because the `this` in inner function is the instance's `this`.

For more information, please refer to the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).